# Query execution hanging in specific circumstances

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, timescaledb

## The problem

For a while now i've encountered a bug where a data retrieval query keeps hanging during execution. If that was all, then debugging would be fine, but it is not easy to reproduce, namely:

- It only occurs on my linux laptop (manjaro xfce), with no problems on my windows pc
- Primarily occurs on a few specific timestamps (mostly 4:05)
- Even then doesn't consistently appear

I know how this can be fixed (by prepending the query with a `select 1;`), but i don't understand **why** the problem occurs, and **why** my solution fixes it, which is where i'm stuck. I've not seen any other problems that specifically describe this issue.

### Code

The query in question below. What is does is select a range of measurements, and then averaging those measurements per timestep (and interpolating in case it's necessary) to get a range of averages.

```sql
SELECT datetime, AVG(wc) as wc
FROM (
    SELECT public.time_bucket_gapfill('5 minutes', m.datetime)
    AS datetime, public.interpolate(AVG(m.wc)) as wc
    FROM growficient.measurement AS m
    INNER JOIN growficient.placement AS p ON m.placement_id = p.id
    WHERE m.datetime >= '2022-09-30T22:00:00+00:00'
    AND m.datetime < '2022-10-01T04:05:00+00:00'
    AND p.section_id = 'bd5114b8-4aab-11eb-af66-32bd66d4e25c'
    GROUP BY public.time_bucket_gapfill('5 minutes', m.datetime), p.id
) AS placement_averages
GROUP BY datetime
ORDER BY datetime;
```

This is then executed via SQLAlchemy on a session level. In case the bug appears, it never gets to the fetchall().

```py
execute_result = session.execute(query)
readings = execute_result.fetchall()
```

We're using session management very similar to what's seen in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#migrating-from-the-subtransaction-pattern). This is meant to be a debug-session however, meaning that no commit statements are included.

```py
sessionMaker = sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    bind=create_engine(
        config.get_settings().main_db,
        echo=False,
        connect_args=connect_options,
        pool_pre_ping=True,
    ),
)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def managed_session() -> Session:
    session = sessionMaker()
    try:
        yield session
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        logger.error("Session error: %s", e)
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
```

### Observations

- I can visually see the transaction hanging if i execute `select * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity psa` [image: attachment]
- Printing the identical query and then executing it inside the database directly (i.e. dbeaver) correctly returns the results
- None of the timeouts mentioned in [the Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html) do anything to break out of the hang
- Adding a `SELECT 1;` statement works, but setting `pool_pre_ping=True` in the engine doesn't, which confuses me as they do the same thing to my understanding.

Comment: try setting `autoflush` to `True`

Comment: If that `pg_stat_activity` line is actually the correct one, your statement is done, but the transaction is still open (start "idle in transaction").

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen This doesn't change the results. What was the intent behind setting it? Since i thought flushing is only relevant for object changes (e.g. additions), which isn't the case here

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Good to know. That is indeed the line yes. Do you have a clue what is causing this behaviour? I can't close this transaction myself either, since it never goes past the execute() line